# How to enable anti aliasing with deferred rendering path in VR (pico4) ? Unity 2021.3.21f1

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to enable anti aliasing with deferred rendering path in VR (pico4) ?
Unity 2021.3.21f1

Smoothing does not work when switching to PICO 4